# How to print \tilde{\mathscr{H}}?

Tags: overleaf

The code $\tilde{\mathscr{H}}$ doesn't work. Is there any solution?

Comment: Welcome! Are you doing `\usepackage{mathrsfs}`?

Comment: @egreg no. I'll try it.

Comment: @egreg It doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it does, see answer below.

Comment: "It does not work" does not help. If you can't get the suggestion in the comment working, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), so that others can understand the context of your code.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get `\mathscr` you need a package that supports it, for instance `mathrsfs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

$\tilde{\mathscr{H}}$ or $\widetilde{\mathscr{H}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, with less dramatic slant, `rsfso`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[scr]{rsfso}

\begin{document}

$\tilde{\mathscr{H}}$ or $\widetilde{\mathscr{H}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/project/6500633f6f732abf94205062 Please check row 384, 385 and 386.

Comment: main/chap/1.tex

Comment: @rushusuixing Nobody else than you can access that project.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/3425188377nmxkvhhjdzbb#c7485c
 Edition is accessed.

Comment: @rushusuixing you have still made it only accessible to users logged in to overleaf. Do not use external links make a small self contained document that shows the problem and add it to your question. It need not be any larger than the documents egreg shows here.

Comment: @egreg I deleted the package "unicode-math" and solved the problem. So why?